# Is the absolute value of the derivative of a BV function equal to the derivative of its total variation?

Tags: real-analysis

For a given function $f\in BV([0,1])$, its function of total variation $V_f(x)$ is defined by $V_f(x)=sup_{0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=x,\ n\in\mathbb N}\{\Sigma_{i=1}^n|f(t_i)-f(t_{i-1})|\}$, then  $f$ and $V_f$ is differentiable almost everywhere, and by Jordan's decomposition theorem, we have $|f'(x)|\leq V_f'(x)$

Furthermore， I wonder if $|f'(x)|= V_f'(x)$ almost everywhere or not, since this statement holds for all monotone functions, and every BV function could be decomposited to two monotone functions.

Any suggestion is welcomed, thanks a lot!

Comment: You missed an absolute value sign.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Sorry, now I have revised it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference to a proof.

**Cater, F. S. A new elementary proof of a theorem of de la Vallée Poussin.
Real Anal. Exchange 27 (2001/02), no. 1, 393–396.**

> *Summary:* "We give a new elementary proof of the classical theorem: Let $f$ be of bounded variation on $[a,b]$ and let $V$ be its total
> variation function. Then there is a set $N $  such that
> $m(V(N))=m(f(N))=m(N)=0$, and for each $x$ not in $N$, $f$ and $V$
> have derivatives, finite or infinite, and $V′(x)=|f′(x)|$.''

Here $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure and $f(N)$ and $V(N)$ are the images under $f$ and $V$ of the set $N$.   Note this doesn't say that at every point where one of  $f'(x)$ and $V'(x)$ exist they are equal.  Consider $f(x)=|x|$ which has no derivative at $x=0$ but its total variation function does.

In the Monthly article cited below, the author gives some examples where $f'(x)$ and $V'(x)$ both exist and have different values.  Thus the de la Vallée Poussin theorem just describes the set on which they exist and agree, not individual points.

**G. A. Heuer.  The Derivative of the Total Variation Function. The American Mathematical Monthly, Dec., 1971, Vol. 78, No. 10 (Dec., 1971), pp. 1110-1112.**